# Published artifacts not found in the directory nor available for download in Azure pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm creating a file and publishing it like this.

```
- job: first_job
  displayName: "Publishing"
  steps:
  - pwsh: | 
      New-Item arty.txt -ItemType File
      Get-ChildItem $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
  - publish: arty.txt
    artifact: arty
  - pwsh: Get-ChildItem $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
```

I can confirm that the craeated list is listed in my working directory. I also see in the log that the publishing seems to be successful.

> Task         : Publish Pipeline Artifacts
> ...
> Artifact name input: arty
> Uploading pipeline artifact from /home/vsts/work/1/s/arty.txt for build #5850
> ...
> 1 files processed.
> Processed 1 files from /home/vsts/work/1/s successfully.
> Uploaded 0 out of 173 bytes
> Content upload is done!

Content upload statistics:
Total Content: 0.2 KB
Physical Content Uploaded: 0.0 bytes
Logical Content Uploaded: 0.0 bytes
Compression Saved: 0.0 bytes
Deduplication Saved: 0.2 KB
Number of Chunks Uploaded: 0
Total Number of Chunks: 3

Associated artifact 3569 with build 5850

When I try to download it like this:

```
- job: second_job_with
  displayName: "Downloading"
  steps:
  - download: current
    artifact: arty
```

I get the error telling me that the artifact *arty* isn't available in the build 5850.

> Starting: Download
> ...
> Download from the specified build: #5850
> Download artifact to: /home/vsts/work/1/arty
> ...
> ##[error]Artifact arty was not found for build 5850.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong or how to analyse it further. Trying to list the artifact directory right after the publish produces an empty response. However, I'm not sure if it's supposed to be filled with *arty.txt* or whatever else I'm supposed to see there. Not even sure if I'm checking the right directory.

Comment: `Uploaded 0 out of 173 bytes` - it looks like nothing uploaded, can you share the full yaml pipeline?